# Change post-type rewrite previously defined

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

My site includes a third party plugin which includes the below:

`register_post_type( 'portfolio',
...
'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio'  )
...
)`

However for my site I need it to effectively say

`...
'rewrite'            => array( 'with_front' => false, 'slug' => 'portfolio' )
...`

However I don't want to edit this third party plugin and cause problems for future updating. Is it possible to define the extra argument in my own plugin or theme (I don't think a theme can change rewrite)?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else, the solution I've arrived at after another frustrating day working on this was to create a new plugin which read in all the existing plugin details via

`get_post_types(array('name' => 'portfolio'),'objects');`

edit the rewrite

`$rebuiltportfolio["rewrite"]=array('with_front' => false, 'slug' => 'portfolio');`

and then re-registered the post type

`register_post_type( 'portfolio', $rebuiltportfolio);`

You do need to ensure that this action has a higher priority than the original one.